# Single-spa projects splitting

Tags: javascript, webpack, microservices

I am new in this. I want to build micro-ui app. I am going to use single-spa framework. So I want to have 3 separate folders with different kind of ui apps. And I want to build them separately. Is this possible? How can I do it?

For know I have 2 react apps and one single-spa app (which import another applications). I have 1 package.json\webpack.config\babel files. So I want to separate these applications (like put them into different local disks (C, D, e.c.t.)).

For example: I want to rebuild one of my applications without rebuilding every apps (just one which I changed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a github project, which I used in my previous work, to implement multiple standalone micro-apps managed separately and deployed separately, using single-spa.

Have a look at it and it may give you some ideas.

https://github.com/agrawald/micro-frontend-single-spa

Use the following commands to clone the repo

`git clone https://github.com/agrawald/micro-frontend-single-spa`

`cd micro-frontend-single-spa`

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

Let me know if you have issues.

Comment: @pheonix : I tried downloading your code from github both using a zip download and by using git clone. But the folders of each microsfrontend are empty when I download. Can you please help?

Comment: @AmolKshirsagar I have update the readme with the command required to git clone the repo

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure If I understood your question properly, but I would suggest not to concentrate on folder/file physical structure. I would recommend to look into the [microfrontends](https://martinfowler.com/articles/micro-frontends.html).

For example, you can have many different applications that could be build and delivered separately. Every microfrontend app could be whatever you want, like React App, plain jquery, or whatever you came up with.

Let's imagine you have your main index file which will contain:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="app-container"></div>
<body>
</html>
```

So having that, you will inject into your *app-container* appropriate application based on your route while your template is rendered on the server.

```
// some code in the Controller that you going to build for your app
public function getFrontendApp(Route)
{

    case Route.mainPage:
         return <div>This Is React App!</div>
    case Route.shoppingList:
         return <div>This is jquery!<div>

    // somewhere here you will also inject css or js bundles for every app 
}
```

Or even if you don't want to build a server you can just inject your bundles manually. Just by referencing to them after you build your applications.

```
// https://myshop.com/home
(home.html)
<html>
<head>Home Page</head>
<link href="react-css-bundle.css"/>
<body>
    <div id="app-container">
        <div>My React App!</div>
    </div>
<body>
<script src="my-react-app-bundle.js"/>
</html>

//https://myshop.com/list
(list.html)
<html>
<head>Shopping List</head>
<link href="jquery-bundle.css"/>
<body>
    <div id="app-container">
        <div>My JQUERY App!</div>
    </div>
<body>
<script src="my-jquery-bundle-app.js"/>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @alexlz, I will definately try this.